# Error using getSymbols in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I try to write a short report using `rmarkdown` where I would like to download market data from yahoo using the function `getSymbolds` of the `quantmod` package.

````
---
title: "TEST"
author: "TEST"
date: "Monday, January 25, 2016"
output: html_document
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
require(quantmod)
prices = invisible(getSymbols("^GDAXI", return.class = "xts", auto.assign=FALSE ))
cat(getwd())
rets = na.omit(diff(log(prices[,4]))) - mean(na.omit(diff(log(prices[,4]))))
plot(rets['2015/2016'])
```
````

However, the call     `prices = invisible(getSymbols("^GDAXI", return.class = "xts", auto.assign=FALSE ))` does not work and I get the error message:

```
Quitting from lines 8-13 (Preview-1a04527111.Rmd) 
Error in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GDAXI&a=0&b=01&c=2007&d=0&e=25&f=2016&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=^GDAXI&x=.csv'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... getSymbols -> do.call -> getSymbols.yahoo -> download.file

Execution halted
```

When I run the R code line by line in usual R mode then I get the expected results. Is there a known issue with `getSymbols` and `rmarkdown`?

My `sessionInfo()` is

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] quantmod_0.4-5      TTR_0.23-0          xts_0.9-7           zoo_1.7-12          stochvol_1.2.2      coda_0.18-1        
 [7] XLConnect_0.2-11    XLConnectJars_0.2-9 plyr_1.8.3          reshape_0.8.5       svDialogs_0.9-57    svGUI_0.9-55       
[13] RODBC_1.3-12       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.8    grid_3.1.3      htmltools_0.2.6 lattice_0.20-30 Rcpp_0.12.1     rJava_0.9-7     rmarkdown_0.9.2 tools_3.1.3    
[9] yaml_2.1.13
```

EDIT after the comment: using setInternet2(use=TRUE) made it work. The following works - even in my company security setting.

````
---
title: "TEST"
author: "TEST"
date: "Monday, January 25, 2016"
output: html_document
---
```{r, echo=FALSE}
require(quantmod)
setInternet2(use = TRUE)
prices = invisible(getSymbols("^GDAXI", return.class = "xts", auto.assign=FALSE ))
cat(getwd())
rets = na.omit(diff(log(prices[,4]))) - mean(na.omit(diff(log(prices[,4]))))
plot(rets['2015/2016'])
```
````

Comment: Works perfectly with me. Just I get the following warning:     
   ## Warning in download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=",
     ## from.m, : downloaded length 180878 != reported length 200

Comment: Do you get this if you knit the script to html?

Comment: what is your  `sessionInfo()`  ?

Comment: I am behind a company firewall. I just wonder if it works just using R directly and it does not work running knit.

Comment: Yes, Even when I knit the .rmd, it works fine. I have the same config as you except rmarkdown which is 0.9 instead of 0.9.2.

Comment: Then it  must be something with the firewall ... and my IT department is not very helpful in such things ...

Comment: Try the option setInternet2() as well. Could bypass some proxy issue.

Comment: Yes, setInternet2(use = TRUE) worked!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your proxy issue, use `setInternet2()`.

From a more general point of view, I prefer to manually download the file, save it in a `.rdata` file (with `save()`) and use `load()` in your rmarkdown file.

It makes your knit faster(unless you are used of the cache or don't do mistakes) and don't dl multiple time the same file. (only in the case it is a one shot analysis and not a report)

Comment: Yes, this is the way ... it would have been nice to have the download in the markdown file ... for automatic update as time goes by ...